# How can I restrict the access to the cluster or to the cluster resources ( namespaces, pods ...)?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kubernetes-rbac

I have a kubernetes cluster installed using 5 Virtual machines. 1 for the kubernetes master, and the other for the workers.

I tried using RBAC method, I created a kubeconfig file to give access to only one namespace, when I test it using (kubectl --kubeconfig developper.kubeconfig get pods), it works but if this user didn't use the flag --kubeconfig, he can simply use: kubectl get all --all-namespaces( for axample ) and he will be able the access to all the cluster resources, So this is not the efficient method that I need.

**Do you have any other solutions please?**

Comment: Are you using a cloud provider managed solution like AKS (azure), EKS (aws), GKE (gcp) or others  ?

Comment: no, i'm on local servers